# can't connect to pi over USB C cable

Tags: usb, headless

I tried a couple different guides on how to do this:

https://howchoo.com/pi/raspberry-pi-gadget-mode/

https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-connect-raspberry-pi-to-laptop-or-pc-usb/

They differ in whether otg_mode=1 needs to be commented out but it doesn't seem to matter.  Either way I get some hopeful dmesg entries when I plug the pi into the laptop via a USB C cable:

```
1063   │ [  184.967334] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
1064   │ [  187.148987] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
1065   │ [  187.406913] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=a4a2, bcdDevice= 6.06
1066   │ [  187.406927] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
1067   │ [  187.406932] usb 1-1: Product: RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget
1068   │ [  187.406935] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Linux 6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8 with fe980000.usb
1069   │ [  187.433189] cdc_ether 1-1:1.0 usb0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 66:aa:0f:fc:ba:f3
1070   │ [  187.433263] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
1071   │ [  187.433285] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_subset
1072   │ [  187.440766] cdc_ether 1-1:1.0 enx66aa0ffcbaf3: renamed from usb0
```

and the device shows up in `/sbin/ifconfig` output:

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig
enx66aa0ffcbaf3: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 66:aa:0f:fc:ba:f3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 631  bytes 67147 (67.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 631  bytes 67147 (67.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.119  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::530:f932:4081:acf3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 64:49:7d:c1:66:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6049  bytes 5191642 (5.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3894  bytes 906329 (906.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` just waits a bit and says Could not resolve hostname

I tried some manual `ifconfig enx66aa0ffcbaf3 192.168.0.169` (a free address on my network) but then `ssh pi@192.168.0.169` gives immediate Connection refused.  And that doesn't seem quite right since it's on a different network.  I really don't know what manual network config incantation to try.

Is there any way to get AVAHI to just work?  Is there some other way to get things going from where I am?

Comment: An immediate "connection refused" means the address is valid and there is a system/device online there, but the SSH port is not open  -- ie., either it is not the system/device you think is there or it is not running ssh on the default port.  Note that assigning "a free address on my network" to an interface that is not on that network is bound to fail and cause problems because of routing, eg., even on the Pi itself 192.168.0.0/24 will be routed through `wlo1`, and not automagically on the usbeth one just because you gave it a bogus address.  Have a look at `ip route`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if avahi-daemon service is running.  You can do this by running:

```
sudo service avahi-daemon status
```

If it's not running, start it with:

```
sudo service avahi-daemon start
```

Answer (score 0):

The guides you read seem to assume there is some networking software that is going to take care of the interface.  Based on the fact that they were both written last year slightly before or around the time the latest version of the OS was released, presumably that's dhcpcd, which is not used on the latest release and may explain why it hasn't been configured.

I don't use the default networking software but I can tell you want needs to be done sans interference from such.

It is sort of implied in your question you are running linux on the laptop as well -- I'm guessing that's where the log output is from and it isn't clear where the `ifconfig` output is from.

In any case, the usb eth interface doesn't have an address assigned and as per my comment on the question simply assigning it a `192.168.0.x` address when that is the prefix of your wifi network will not work.

Instead, you need to use a subnet prefix that is *not* otherwise in use.  I'll use `10.10.42.0/24`.  On which ever system has the `enx66aa0ffcbaf3` interface:

```
sudo ip addr add 10.10.42.1/24 dev enx66aa0ffcbaf3
```

The kernel will probably set a route for this; you can check with `ip route`, which should include something like:

```
10.10.42.0/24 dev enx66aa0ffcbaf3 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.42.1
```

If not:

```
ip route add 10.10.42.0/24 dev enx66aa0ffcbaf3
```

Repeat that on the system at the other end of the cable, except use `10.10.42.2` in the `ip addr add`.

You should then have access using those addresses.  I don't know if avahi will apply itself, but it is a bit pointless -- there's only two nodes in that subnet and they both have fixed addreses.

They will not be accessible from the internet or your lan unless you add some forwarding rules on one side.